# -bash export : not a valid identifier

Tags: macos, android-studio, flutter, terminal

I've recently edited some line in my /.bash_profile on my MacBook to add firebase to my school project.

I used `echo export PATH="$PATH:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/bin"` but it did not work as I wanted(it did add in ~/.bash_profile) so i deleted it using `sed $d ~/.bash_profile` and checked with `cat ~/.bash_profile`. And then I saw it did not change anything (or it did but I did not know), i ran the sed command for a few times and checked with cat and terminal still displayed the same code.

However, after those changes, whenever I start terminal, it will always display these 2 lines:

```
bash: export: `Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/bin:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/bin': not a valid identifier

bash: export: `Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/bin:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/bin': not a valid identifier
```

Here is my ~/.bash_profile

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave`
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin"
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/bin:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/bin
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/bin:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/bin
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/bin"
```

I have checked this [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/881261/terminal-new-window-always-shows-bash-searching-command-not-found) with similar errors and they say to comment the error lines but when I comment the 2 lines, terminal cannot run some basic commands like cat, mv or nano.

So i have some questions about the error.

1. How does this error affect anything on my system? (although my app is still running fine)
2. Is it bad for my laptop? And how can I solve the error?
3. (Out of topic) Why does it has to relate to python? Is it because of Python IDLE that i installed it before?

Comment: You have a bunch of problems due to incorrect quoting in your shell commands; for example, in `sed $d ~/.bash_profile`, the `$d` will be "expanded" to the value of the variable `d`, which probably doesn't exist, so it effectively vanished from the command and `sed` did something different from what you wanted. There are similar problems in the `echo`, but they don't quite match the damage in your .bash_profile. To fix this, you'll have to rebuild the .bash_profile from scratch. What's in .bash_profile.pysave?

Comment: @Gordon I tried to google where is .bash_profile.pysave and i found [This page](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3970816), i use the command `grep -i pysave ~/* ~/.*` and here is what it show:
/Users/quanan/.bash_profile:# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave     
grep: /Users/quanan/.bash_sessions: Is a directory     
grep: /Users/quanan/.config: Is a directory     
There is more but it is too long and looks the same. It seems like there is no .bash_profile.pysave in my computer. What can i do

Comment: Just use `cat ~/.bash_profile.pysave` (the page you found concerns finding things that *use* the .pysave file, not the file itself).

Comment: I just did and the terminal says `No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what's gone wrong, or how your .bash_profile *should* be set up. At this point, I'd recommend just completely replacing it (probably in a text editor -- trying to use shell commands may just cause more problems). Here's my best guess at what it should contain:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

PATH="$PATH:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/share/dotnet"
PATH="$PATH:~/.dotnet/tools"
PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands"
PATH="$PATH:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/bin"
PATH="$PATH:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/bin"
```

Some of these additions to `PATH` may be redundant/irrelevant; I can't tell without knowing way more about how your system is set up and what tools you're using.

As for what caused this, it looks like some of the problems due to incorrect quoting. For instance, if you used this (note: I don't think is *exactly* what you did):

echo export PATH="$PATH:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/bin" >>~/.bash_profile

...then what the shell would have done is replace the `$PATH` with the current value of the `PATH` variable before passing the string to `echo` (which is not what you want -- you want it to add `$PATH` *literally* to the
.bash_profile, so it gets expanded only when that script runs). Also, the double-quotes are removed before it's handed to `echo`, so what `echo` actually prints is something like:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/bin:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/bin
```

...and since that *doesn't* have the double-quotes, the space in the "...VMware Fusion.app..." part is treated as a separator between two separate things to export, and the second one (starting "Fusion.app/Contents/Public..." isn't a valid variable name, you get an error. Plus, the first part is clearly incomplete, so it doesn't cause an error but it doesn't do the right thing either.

To get the variables to expand correctly and at the right times, you *must* use something more like this:

echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/Users/quanan/Downloads/flutter/bin"' >>~/.bash_profile

Here, the single-quotes around the whole thing tell the shell to just treat the `$` and double-quotes as literal characters, so they pass straight through and get included in what's added to the .bash_profile script. Then, when that runs, the double-quotes allow the `$PATH` bit to expand, but prevent the "...VMware Fusion.app..." part from being split.

The moral here is that quoting is critical; not just doing it, but doing it *right*. If you don't understand what quotes do (and what's different between single- and double-quotes), you should be careful to copy someone who does, or at least check the result to make sure it's doing what you think it is.